# arc with navigation delegate error property delegate not found on object of type viewcontroller

Tags: ios5, delegates, uinavigationcontroller, automatic-ref-counting, syntax-error

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on my question below.

I'm getting a property delegate not found on object of type viewcontroller error on when I declare the delegate in the parent view:

[image: delegate error]

Here's the relevant code in the parent .h file:

```
@protocol ModalViewDelegate 
- (void)didReceiveFrequencyMessage:(NSString *)message;
@end

@interface jhsManageRemindersViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, ModalViewDelegate>
```

and here's where I call the child view:

```
    jhsScheduleViewController *jhsScheduleController = [[jhsScheduleViewController alloc]
                                              initWithNibName:@"jhsScheduleViewControllerr" bundle:nil];
    
jhsScheduleController.delegate = self;
// Create the navigation controller and present it modally.
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                initWithRootViewController:jhsScheduleController];
navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

and here's part of my child .h file

```
@protocol ModalViewDelegate ;

@interface jhsScheduleViewController : UIViewController {
    //id<ModalViewDelegate> delegate;
//       __unsafe_unretained id <ModalViewDelegate> _delegate;
    __weak id <ModalViewDelegate> delegate;
    NSMutableString *message;    
}

@property ( weak) id<ModalViewDelegate> delegate;
//@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ModalViewDelegate> delegate;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *message;
```

and finally, here's my .m usage

```
@synthesize delegate;
//@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
```

I've viewed and tried various solutions based upon Stackoverflow questions and this recommended [blogpost](http://vinceyuan.blogspot.com/2011/06/wwdc2011-session-323-introducing.html). I've included some of my attempted solutions in commented out code, just as an FYI.

I started with the code I had in an iOS4 app but that generates the error. As a footnote, this is an app with a TabBarController and a NavigationController

Can someone tell me how to fix this so the delegate error can be resolved?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure what the problem was. But as a last resort, I saved every file, then tried to build it, with Xcode still reporting the error, which worked.

Actually, there was an error in the initWithNibName but it ran fine until it got to that point, and correcting the typo fixed that. Again, I'm not sure what the problem was but I seem to be on my way.